# What items are unavailable after the late game changes to Leyndell, Royal Capital?

Tags: elden-ring

After defeating the final boss in Farum Azula,

> Leyndell is burned down

and many areas and mobs are no longer accessible.

A good example of this is the two [Duelist enemies](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Duelist) near the Colosseum (near the West Capital Ramparts grace), who are the only sources for a few armor pieces (the Gravekeeper Cloak, Duelist Helm and Greaves) and weapons (the Duelist Greataxe and Battle Hammer). After the changes to the capital, they cannot be fought, and their drops can’t be acquired until returning in New Game+.

What’s the full list of **unique** items that cannot be acquired after the changes to the zone?

For the purpose of this question, a ‘unique’ item can be defined as: weapons or armor that cannot be acquired elsewhere, talismans, spells, incantations, ashes of war, pots/perfume Bottles, crafting recipes, and other similar items. Top tier smithing stones/gloveworts should count as well, but not the ordinary 1-9 items that can eventually be bought.

Comment: For those looking to draft an answer; the wiki page for Leyndell is a good starting point, and I _think_ is comprehensive with respect to boss drops and items that are sitting in chests/on the ground in fixed locations, but is missing the item drops from enemies like the aforementioned Duelists that cannot be acquired elsewhere. https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Leyndell+Royal+Capital

Answer (score -1):

The only "necessary" item I can think of in Leyndell is the Bolt of Gransax, which is required for the "Legendary Armaments" achievement, other than that I second LessPop's suggestion to take a look at the wiki page.